# Upgraded to 12.10, and now most of my installed GNOME Shell extensions are "outdated"

Tags: gnome

I love the look of GNOME Shell, but the extensions are what make it usable for me. However, after the 12.10 upgrade, all but a few no longer work. Is there a way to get them back manually, or must I wait until the extension authors make updates for Quantal Quetzal?

I'm using gnome-shell 3.6.1 and installed the extensions using extensions.gnome.org.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.noobslab.com/2012/10/install-gnome-shell-36-and-gnome-shell.html

this helped me, but it contains only some of them...I don't do how to get the others, because from the website they don't work...even if you put them on ''on'' mode, they're not installed

Answer (score 0):

****DOH**** just noticed this question was a bit long in the tooth. Answer still applies, but is probably not particularly relevant any longer.

---

You can **try** to update them manually where the author hasn't updated their extensions, though they may or may not actually work.

If you've installed the extensions locally for your user (likely when using extensions.gnome.org), the extensions will be in

> ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions/

Within that directory will be one directory for each extension in the form **extension@something** . Within each **extension@something** directory will be several files, open the one named **metadata.json**. You'll see a line something like:

> "shell-version": ["3.6.1"]

modify that line by adding **,"3.8"** (or whatever version of gnome-shell you're running) to it:

> "shell-version": ["3.6.1", "3.8"]

Save and repeat for each extension that doesn't work. Then logout/login. This will work so long as nothing else changed in the newer gnome-shell that the extension relied upon. This is not a given. IF there are any problems, remove your modification (just the part you added , not the whole line).

Comment: It might suffice to hit ALT+F2 and enter "restart" instead of logout/login.

Comment: You are right, it would. I do notice that restarting fails inexplicably sometimes where a logout/login does not. Still, restarting alone should suffice.